# Insert multiple entries into one table - dynamic values

Tags: php

I am trying to insert multiple values into one table. First, I have the user select the number of `instructors`. Based on the initial selection, jquery displays the number of inputs display that correspond to it. So if the user selects two instructors, then two input fields will appear. I would like two insert the values of both input fields into mysql database. Right now, nothing is being inserted and I am not sure the cause. [SITE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/test/index.php).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
                    var num = $('.clonedSection').length;
                    var newNum = new Number(num + 1);

                    var newSection = $('#pq_entry_' + num).clone().attr('id', 'pq_entry_' + newNum);

                    newSection.children(':first').children(':first').attr('id', 'inst_fname_' + newNum).attr('name', 'inst_fname_' + newNum).attr('placeholder', 'Instructor #' + newNum + ' First Name');

                    newSection.children(':nth-child(2)').children(':first').attr('id', 'inst_lname_' + newNum).attr('name', 'inst_lname_' + newNum);

                    newSection.insertAfter('#pq_entry_' + num).last();

                    $('#btnDel').prop('disabled', '');

                    if (newNum == 5) $('#btnAdd').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
                });

                $('#btnDel').click(function () {
                    var num = $('.clonedSection').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                    $('#pq_entry_' + num).remove(); // remove the last element

                    // enable the "add" button
                    $('#btnAdd').prop('disabled', '');

                    // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
                    if (num - 1 == 1) $('#btnDel').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
                });

                $('#btnDel').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
            });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
Instructor:
            <ul id="pq_entry_1" class="clonedSection">
                <li>
                    <input id="inst_fname_1" name="inst_fname_1" placeholder="Instructor #1 - First Name" type="text" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input id="inst_lname_1" name="inst_lname_1" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" />
                </li>
            </ul>

            <input type='button' id='btnAdd' value='add another instructor' />
            <input type='button' id='btnDel' value='delete instructor' />
</br>
<input value="SAVE" type="submit">
<?php

$db_con = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
} 
$db_insert3 = "INSERT INTO instructor (`instructor_fname`, `instructor_lname`)";
$db_insert3 .= " VALUES ('" . $_POST['inst_fname_1'] ."', '" . $_POST['inst_lname_1'] ."')";
        mysqli_query($db_con, $db_insert3);
?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the input values in an array.Like this:

```
<input id="inst_fname_1" name="inst_fname_1[]" placeholder="Instructor #1 - First Name" type="text" />

<input id="inst_lname_1" name="inst_lname_1[]" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" />
```

On the server-side, use `foreach` to retrieve the value from array and insert it into database.

```
foreach($_POST['inst_fname_1'] as $fname){
// insert query
}
```

**Note:** Your insert query should be outside the form and use `isset` to check if the form is submitted or not.

Updated **html:**

```
<form action="" method="post">
Instructor:
        <ul id="pq_entry_1" class="clonedSection">
            <li>
                <input id="inst_fname_1" name="inst_fname_1[]" placeholder="Instructor #1 - First Name" type="text" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <input id="inst_lname_1" name="inst_lname_1[]" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" />
            </li>
        </ul>

        <input type='button' id='btnAdd' value='add another instructor' />
        <input type='button' id='btnDel' value='delete instructor' />
</br>
<input value="SAVE" type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

**Note:** Here i have left form `action` field blank because my php code is on the top of the same page.

Updated **javascript:**

```
 newSection.children(':first').children(':first').attr('id', 'inst_fname_' + newNum)
 .attr('name', 'inst_fname_1[]').attr('placeholder', 'Instructor #' + newNum + ' First Name');

 newSection.children(':nth-child(2)').children(':first').
 attr('id', 'inst_lname_' + newNum).attr('name', 'inst_lname_1[]');
```

Updated **php**:

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$db_con = new mysqli(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
if ($db_con->connect_errno) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $db_con->connect_error);
exit();
}
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['inst_fname_1']);$i++){
    $db_insert3 = "INSERT INTO  instructor (instructor_fname,instructor_lname) 
             VALUES ('".$_POST['inst_fname_1'][$i]."','".$_POST['inst_lname_1'][$i]."')";
    $db_con->query($db_insert3);

    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Made the changes, but nothing is being inserted into the database.

Comment: I copied and pasted everything exactly but nothing is being stored in the database

Comment: Check if your database connection code is correct and post the php code on the top of the same page. Use `print_r($_POST['inst_fname_1'])` and check for elements in the array.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40931/discussion-between-code-ed-student-and-joke-sense10)